# Does Nyu have Vectors?

Tags: elfen-lied

Does Nyu have Vectors? And if not, why?

I notice that when Lucy's mind switches to Nyu (looks like), there are no Vectors anymore, aren't there? And most of all, is Nyu a Diclonius?

Comment: Yes, she definitely has vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Nyu is a Diclonious, she's a regressed split personality of Lucy. They share the same body

Whilst it's not explained in depth how Vectors work, it's understood that Vectors are controlled by the user's mind and are telepathic in nature.

Vectors come in several potencies depending on the frequency of the user's brainwaves:

- Low frequency - Can go through objects without causing physical interference.
- Medium frequency - Can lift objects and throw them, as well as disrupt blood vessels.
- High frequency - Can slash through wood, flesh, bone and rock. Can carry liquid on surface.
- Extremely high frequency - Highly visible and gain potentially explosive power.

[Reference - Elfen Lied Wikia on Vectors](http://elfen-lied.wikia.com/wiki/Vectors)

When Lucy is 'Nyu', her intellect and capabilities vastly drop. You may remember when she wet herself in Kouta's house, or the fact that she could only say Nyu when she first met Kouta. We can assume from this that her ability to manifest Vectors is inaccessible due to the decreased mental ability she has with this personality change.

Comment: I can't remember if Nana was only able to detect Lucy, rather than Nyu - I haven't watched the series in a while - but if so, that was probably based on the strong brainwaves active diclonius emit

Comment: No your right. When Nana is first sent out to find Lucy she can't sense her and when she first meets Nyu she knows she's Lucy but can understand why she can't sense her. When Lucy and Nyu switches she starts sensing Lucy again.

Comment: @Why_SE_bulling_new_users I wouldn't quite say that. They are physically the same body. But when in her Nyu state, she cannot access her vectors and can't do a lot of other things. With her personality change, she can't be sensed by other diclonius. I would say this is because whatever stimuli that the diclonius emit that is used for sensing each other, is severely lowered in her Nyu state. So you *could* say "she becomes more human in the physical and biological sense", but she is still biologically a diclonius.

Comment: @Why_SE_bulling_new_users. You should not think of vectors as physical features like "arms", you should think of them as mental ones, like the ability to speak. Nyu *has* a voice, she *has* vectors; she just doesn't know how to use them.